# check if Rails partial is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a main page that is responsible for HTML/CSS styling, but some of the contents come from partials. A partial receives some locals or params, i.e. current_user or person, and displays information if any.

Is there a way for me to check if a partial rendered anything? My end goal is something like this:

```
<% if my_partial can render something %>
 <div class="css_for_something">
  <%= render(partial: 'my_partial', locals: {...} ) %>
<% else %>
  <div class="css_for_no_info">
   <%= render something else %>
<% end %>
```

I do not want the partials to handle styling logic; they just need to display content if any. Conversely, the main page should not know anything about the logic in the partial(s), such as checking values or querying the database.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the value generated by `render_to_string` in a variable:

```
<% partial_content = render_to_string(partial: 'my_partial', locals: {...} ).strip %>
```

Then you can see if it contains any content:

```
<% if partial_content.present? %>
  <%= partial_content %>
<% else %>
  <div class="css_for_no_info">
    <%= render something else %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @RyanBigg That would be much better. Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Chris Peter's solution did not work for me on rails 4.2.4, as `render_to_string` seems to not be available in views.

However, the following worked (rails 4.2.4):

```
<% partial_content = render partial: 'my_partial' %>
<% if partial_content.present? %>
  <%= partial_content %>
<% else %>
  <%# rendered if partial is empty %>
<% end %>
```

Be aware that the `present?` check really only checks if what was rendered is empty. If, something, e.g. a HTML comment, is returned, the check returns false.